# mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php

Hey I'm a PHP newbie setting up a "fetch, post to db, allow delete" project here and I've fetched the data, printed the DB rows and now I'm adding functionality to delete each row by `'$id'` but I'm running into this error.

I highlighted line 81 with astricks as well as two comment blocks above and below so you can find it easily.

Thanks for helping me learn.

```
<?php

// ***** MagicQuoteFix ***** //

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())  
{  
  function stripslashes_deep($value)  
  {  
    $value = is_array($value) ?  
        array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :  
        stripslashes($value);  
    return $value;  
  }  
  $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);  
  $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);  
  $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);  
  $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);  
} 

// ***** Begin Connection Info ***** //

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ijdbuser', 'ijdbpw');

if (!$connection)
{
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'))
{
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connection, 'ijdb'))
{
    $error = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

// ***** Display DB ***** //

$result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT id, joketext FROM joke');

if (!$result)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $jokes[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['joketext']);
}

if (isset($_GET['addjoke'])) {}

else
{
    include 'jokes.html.php';
}

// 


// ***** Begin Add/Remove DB Options ***** //

if (isset($_GET['addjoke']))
{
    include 'form.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['deletejoke']))
{
// LINE 81 //
******81.****** $id = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']);
// LINE 81 //

    $sql = "DELETE FROM joke WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error deleting joke: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    //header('Location: .');
    exit();

}

if (isset($_POST['joketext']))
{
    $joketext = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['joketext']);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO joke SET
        joketext="' . $_POST['joketext'] . '",
        jokedate=CURDATE()';

    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted joke: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}




?>
```

Comment: it suppose to be mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions? It looks like you are passing the wrong arguments to `mysql_real_escape_string`, but you should use the `mysqli` version of this function instead, or even better, data binding.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara is right. There is a slight difference in syntax between `mysql` and `mysqli` not just the `i`. Consider the `mysqli` functions reference. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderO'Mara. I highly recommend having a look at MySQLi Prepared Statements. This will benefit you in a lot of ways on the long run, like better protection against SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. I'm new but from what I've read now after this comment is that the only difference is there just different extensions? I swear `mysql_real_escape` was working for the form data submission portion. What I don't understand about mysql vs mysqli is one requires data binding? Does data binding just imply "binding data" via a condition?

Comment: and you will get fresh error due to wrong commenting :) ... pls read http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: @user1844933: Honestly, he clearly says he marked it in here for us to see it more easily. He knows that's going to cause problems in any other case.

Comment: How do you know when to use single/double quotes? My lead uses double quotes and only uses singles when there's double quotes in what he's working on so he doesn't have to escape. This tutorial I'm following is mainly using singles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with this line (the one that has the error)

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']);
```

instead it should be

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']);
```

You are mostly handling things as `mysqli_` functions (which is the better way), however in this case you are a using `mysql_` connection for your escape.  **Don't use this, it is deprecated, and soon will no longer work because it is vulnerable to sql injection** The syntax is different for each.  You have the order set up correctly, but have a typo (since everything else is using `mysqli`.  Also **Do not use magic quotes!  Dangerous and deprecated**

Note, there are better ways of handling queries, and you wouldn't need to escape it at all if you use prepared statements (and also not need to worry about whether your variable needs quoting or not).  These are just as secure (some would say more so, so you don't need to *remember* to escape all your variables), and have the advantage of being much faster for larger queries.

For instance, see below. Here's an example using your delete statement:

First connect to the database using an object oriented style like so:

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

(note it's a good idea to store your database variables in a separate script, and then call it as a `require_once` include)

Then, handle your query like this

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM joke WHERE id=?");
$sql->bind_param("i", $id);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

Note that the `"i"` is specifying that this is an integer (as most ids are), however if this variable were a string, you would call specify this as `"s"`

for more information on `mysqli` prepared statements, take a look here:  [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysqli to query to your database therefore you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()` and also remove the first argument that you have passed to the function which is `$connection`. This is a very common mistake every developer makes.

Therefore you can replace line 81 by

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: Which function is wrong for connection? They all make sense don't they?

Comment: @user1844933 You should check [http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp) and also check other comments too

Comment: @tommydevs yes they all make sense but `mysql_` function are compatible only when you use `mysql_connect` to connect to the database. If you are using `mysqli_connect` to connect to the database then you need to use `mysqli_' functions

Comment: pls read difference between Object oriented style coding vs Procedural style

Comment: @tommydevs OK but he have used procedural styles throughout the page MY answer is also correct. and hence you should not down vote it

Comment: The `die` and `mysqli_close` look more familiar to me from my lead developer's work. So I guess I'm just learning.....this tutorial is from 2011...should but I recognize `die` and `mysqli_close` from as far back as 2007 so I dunno what's going on with the author of this tut?

Comment: So my code looks procedural? OOP is just bunching classes and properties together and making it more organized right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: yup and making it easy to understand

Comment: @tommydevs `OOP is just bunching classes and properties together` I've got to remember that one. Gave me a good laugh! :D But no. OOP has a lot more advantages. Just to many to explain in a comment or even in an answer. I simply suggest learning about classes. You'll see the benefits soon enough.

Comment: @UtkarshVishnoi Yes it did. Now I have another problem I'll link to in another 2 hours when I can post. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

similar situation:
please see:www.westwoodpavillion/ecommerce/admin_area/login.php (source code)

```
include("includes/db.php"); 

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
```

it works for me....eloisa..Thank YOu very much.

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
if (!ini_get("safe_mode")) $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $params);
```

to:

```
if (!ini_get("safe_mode")) $success = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $params);
```

> works like magic.. just change your mail($to... and the rest to the
>   specified above)